# How to ignore SwiftUI modal background, or make modal background clear/transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, background, swiftui, transparent

Currently we get a free opaque white/black background for swiftUI modal. Is there anyway to remove the free opaque color and make the modal view transparent?

In the image below, the end result should be able to see the image even with modal presented.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

based on this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/timothycosta/a43dfe25f1d8a37c71341a1ebaf82213) you can create `viewcontroller` extension and modify your presentation.
here is modified code:

```swift
 struct ViewControllerHolder {
    weak var value: UIViewController?
    init(_ value: UIViewController?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ViewControllerKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: ViewControllerHolder { return ViewControllerHolder(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController ) }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var viewController: ViewControllerHolder {
        get { return self[ViewControllerKey.self] }
        set { self[ViewControllerKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func present<Content: View>(presentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, transitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical, animated: Bool = true, completion: @escaping () -> Void = {}, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
        toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = presentationStyle
        toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
            builder()
                .environment(\.viewController, ViewControllerHolder(toPresent))
        )

        toPresent.view.backgroundColor = .clear // This line is modified
        self.present(toPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Your SwiftUI ContentView:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: ViewControllerHolder
    private var viewController: UIViewController? {
        self.viewControllerHolder.value
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Button(action: {
                self.viewController?.present(builder: {
                    Text("OK")
                })
            }) {
               Text("Present me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I implemented it on UIKit view and present it modally, could confirm it also works there as well

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. iOS 14 beta 6.  Copied code exactly.  It presents the modal but with white background, not clear.